# Evaluating the success/failure of a subroutine

Tags: perl, unit-testing, subroutine

There's something quite unclear to me about subs return value.
I like to test my modules, sub by sub, and check whether they issue the correct return value or the correct exception if the case arise.

For example, let's say I have the following code (X::Argument::BadFormat is an exception handler derived from Exception::Class):

```
    package My::Module;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    sub new{#does things unrelated to the current question}

    sub my_sub {
        my ($self,$possible_value) = @_;

        if ($possible_value =~ q{\w}) { #Affect value to current object
            $self->{field} = $possible_value;
        }else{ #throw an exception
            X::Argument::BadFormat->throw(
                arg             => 'possible_value',
                expected_format => 'something that looks like a word',
                received_value  => $possible_value,
            );
        }
    }
```

In the test file, I will run tests such as:

```
my $object = My::Module->new();
throws_ok(sub {$object->my_sub('*')}, 'X::Argument::BadFormat', 'Faulty value will raise an exception');
ok($object->my_sub('turlututu'));
```

It is easy to test when:

- the sub returns a value,
- the test conditions must raise an exception,

However, when I just set the value of a field in the current object, I have no reason to return anything.

In that case:

- is the simple execution of the code enough to evaluate the sub output as "true" ?
- Shall I add an explicit "return 1;" ?
- does the sub actually return the last evaluation, in this case the sucess of the
- test in the "if"? Something else I did not think about but which is
  obvious to everybody?

Comment: why not just check to ensure that the object's attribute was set correctly through the attr directly, or better, through a getter? eg: `my $p='blah'; $obj->my_sub($p); is $obj->{field}, $p, "my_sub() set the field attr ok";`

Comment: Indeed. I realize that I should have phrased my question differently. The actual issue is to be able to evaluate if the subroutine ended correctly, not only for field affectations, but whenever a subroutine is not supposed to return value. Is it clearer this way?

Comment: Oh. reading the question, I understand there is no such thing as a generic answer isn't it? I need to be explicit for my return value or test nay actions it is supposed to have done to my object.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: On a separate note, that test should probably be `$possible_value =~ /\A\w+\z/`, so that the pattern is a regex instead of a single-quoted string, and it checks that the *whole string* consists of "word" characters. What you had will test only that it contained at least one "word" character.

Comment: Indeed. That was just a quick example but you're right nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub that has no need to return a value should end with

```
return;
```

In your case, without it, you will be returning the value of $possible_value, which is the last thing executed.  This doesn't look like a useful thing to return.

Assuming you add the explicit return:

Your `throws_ok` test looks fine.  You should then test that the field was correctly set.  Your `ok` test isn't needed, since your sub won't be returning anything.

Comment: With a caveat though - sometimes `$possible_value` might be evaluated as 'true' and other times false. I'm not convinced that's good, and would tend to prefer an explicit return.

Comment: @Sobrique I prefer *always* doing an explicit return

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear - and sorry for being dense: If I add the explicit retunr at the end, will the ok() test evaluate to true or should I not use this test anyway?

Comment: @David If you have `return;` it will return `undef`. You should have `return;` so you know what you return when no return value is needed. That gives you a stable interface. But `return` is not a true value, so `ok foo()` will fail. As ysth said, you can get rid of that specific test, because all it does is check if the return value is a true value, and that is not a useful test.

Comment: @DavidVerdin instead, since you are essentially writing a setter method, you'd want a test that checks if the value got set correctly. You'd do that by calling the getter. If there is a `$object->field` then you could do `is $object->field, q{turlututu}, q{field got set correctly};`. You can also reach into the underlying hashref, but I would not recommend that. It might also make sense to add another test that checks that `field` wasn't set if the exception is thrown. But that's essentially what stevieb said. Have you looked at Moose?

Comment: @David sometimes setters return the old value that gets overwritten. That might also be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have looked at moose and it looked damn cool. However I heard two critics regarding moose: 1- "It requires a third of CPAN" and 2- "it is not performance-friendly". Are these critics valid according to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130713/discussion-between-david-verdin-and-simbabque).

Comment: to be clear, `return;` returns nothing in list context and `undef` in scalar context.

Comment: No way, the lack of `return` is not a problem. The problem is how the sub is called.

Comment: @ikegami not sure who you are talking to or what your point is.  can you explain?

Comment: @ysth, You said "*A sub that has no need to return a value should end with `return;`*". There's no reason to do that (except as documentation). A sub that doesn't have a return value should not have its return value checked, so adding `return;` doesn't matter. The bug here is not the lack of `return`, but doing `ok(my_sub())`. Note that `ok(my_sub())` will still fail with a `return;`.

Comment: @ikegami: I believe in programming defensively.  The sub should guard against those who do try to use the return value by making it something predictable.  And there wasn't a bug per se in the original code, since the sub would have returned turlututu.  IMO the correct fix is adding an explicit return *and* removing the ok.

Comment: Adding `return;` is not coding defensively since `undef` is just as meaningless as any other value. *Maybe* you'd have a point if you had recommended adding `return 1;`, a true value to indicate the sub succeeded.

Comment: adding return; prevents the return from being unpredictable (for the unwanted few who use the return value).  setting the return value to 1 just for those unwanted few is dumb, and defeats the self-documentation of a `return;` at the end showing that a sub doesn't have return values.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I'd just check to ensure that the object's attribute was set correctly. That's all this particular sub does. If it's set ok, the sub ended correctly. If it wasn't set, something went wrong before the sub ended.

```
my $p='blah'; 
$obj->my_sub($p); 

is $obj->{field}, $p, "my_sub() set the field attr ok";
```

It would be better if the `field` attribute had a getter so you're not breaking encapsulation, but I digress.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sur to check that the object was correctly modified and stop wondering if there exists a magical generic evaluation method.

Answer (score 1):

Perl returns the result of the last executed code by default.

For example:

```
print main();

sub main {
    my $var = 9 * 7;
}
```

`print` will output 63. If your code may be affected by the output of a given subroutine, then you need to set a return value (it's generally considered a best practice to always set an explicit return at the end of a subroutine/method).

```
print main();

sub main {
    my $var = 9 * 7;
    return;
}
```

`print` will output nothing.

Personally, I always try to set a return value depending on the context of what the subroutine will be returning to, but if you're writing code other people will be using, then it's generally safest to just do `return;`.

An additional explanation from Perl::Critic ([link to the specific policy](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/RequireFinalReturn.pm)):

> Subroutine "main" does not end with "return" at line 8, near 'sub main {'.
>
> Subroutines::RequireFinalReturn (Severity: 4)
>
> Require all subroutines to terminate explicitly with one of the
>       following: `return',`carp', `croak',`die', `exec',`exit', `goto', or`
>   throw'.
>
> Subroutines without explicit return statements at their ends can be
>       confusing. It can be challenging to deduce what the return value will
>       be.
>
> Furthermore, if the programmer did not mean for there to be a
>       significant return value, and omits a return statement, some of the
>       subroutine's inner data can leak to the outside. Consider this case:
>
> ```
>    package Password;
>     # every time the user guesses the password wrong, its value
>     # is rotated by one character
>     my $password;
>     sub set_password {
>         $password = shift;
>     }
>     sub check_password {
>         my $guess = shift;
>         if ($guess eq $password) {
>             unlock_secrets();
>         } else {
>             $password = (substr $password, 1).(substr $password, 0, 1);
>         }
>     }
>     1;
> ```
>
> In this case, the last statement in check_password() is the assignment.
>       The result of that assignment is the implicit return value, so a wrong
>       guess returns the right password! Adding a `return;' at the end of that
>       subroutine solves the problem.
>
> The only exception allowed is an empty subroutine.
>
> Be careful when fixing problems identified by this Policy; don't blindly
>       put a `return;' statement at the end of every subroutine.

Comment: You should include a link for the Perl::Critic quote.

Comment: I just ran `perlcritic -1 --verbose 11` from my command line, but here is the cpan page for the module it's from: [Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::RequireFinalReturn](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/RequireFinalReturn.pm)